# Dictionary access and create new keys with a variable value

Tags: python

This is strange, I can create a new key and read as shown below with a variable `x` and `z`. 
Then why can't I do the same further in the index when I am using `x` for reading the key? Is this a bug? How to accomplish this?

```
>>> dict = { 'a':'', 'b':''}
>>> x = 'a'
>>> dict[x]
''
>>> dict[x] = 0
>>> dict[x]
0
>>> dict
{'a': 0, 'b': ''}
>>> z = 'c'
>>> dict[z] = 1
>>> dict
{'a': 0, 'b': '', 'c': 1}
>>>
>>> dict[x][z] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
>>> dict[x][z] = {'c':''}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
>>> dict[x]['d'] = {'c':''}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: What is strange about this? `dict[x]` returns `0`, then you try to index into zero, i.e. `(0)[z]` which throws the TypeError, which is telling you exactly what is wrong. What did you *expect* `dict[x][z] = 1` to do?

Comment: Note, generally, it is safe to assume that it *isn't* a bug in one of the core data structures in the language doing one of it's core functions. Pretty much always it is the programmer's fault.

Comment: At first use of `x` variable value of the `x` is used that is str`a`. Then at the second use of variable `x`  why does it not use str value `a`?

Comment: @KapishM It does. However, `x = 'a'`, and when you use it in line `dict[x][z] = 1` you are writing the equivalent of `dict['a'][z] = 1`, which is the equivalent of `0[z] = 1` (since you had assigned `x = 'a'`, `dict[x] = 0`, `dict['a'] = 0`).

Comment: Then how do I make it to be str value `a` again, in fact always to be str and not key value of `0`

Comment: I don't understand you. A dictionary is defined as pairs of `{key: value}` -- I don't understand what you mean by "make it to be str value `a`" or "not key value of 0" (you don't have a key of `0`, only a value of `0`).

Comment: I want the variable value of `x`, `z` i.e. str to be able to use as key to create nested dict. But not run into the problem of it being `int` paired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your Problem

```py
>>> dict['a']
0
>>> dict
{'a': 0, 'b': ''}

>>> dict['c'] = 1
>>> dict
{'a': 0, 'b': '', 'c': 1}
```

When you do `dict['a']` you will receive the integer `0`, therefore

```py
>>> dict['a']['c'] = 1
```

is equivalent to

```py
>>> 0['c'] = 1
```

Which returns the error you are seeing:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

---

#### Possible Solution

Your "nested" key retrieval can be achieved by putting a `dict` inside a `dict`:

```py
>>> data = {'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': 0}
>>> data
{'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': 0}

>>> data['a']['b'] = 5
>>> data
{'a': {'b': 5}, 'c': 0}
```

You may also do the above by setting `data['a']` to a `dict` after initialization of the original `dict`.

```py
>>> data = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
>>> data
{'a': 0, 'b': 1}

>>> data['a'] = {'c': 2}
>>> data
{'a': {'c': 2}, 'b': 1}

>>> data['a']['c'] = 4
>>> data
{'a': {'c': 4}, 'b': 1}
```

---

### Possible Confusion

Possible confusion might arise when you use a `str` as the value in a `dict`.

```py
>>> data = {'a': "Hello World"}
>>> data
{"a": 'Hello World'}
```

In such case, you *can* do your "nested index":

```py
>>> data['a'][10]
'd'
```

but this is equivalent to

```py
>>> "Hello World"[10]
'd'
```

---

### Sidenote

Don't set variables to the name of [Python's built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) -- in your case, using the name `dict`.

Comment: I want the variable value of `x`, `z` i.e. str to be able to use as key to create nested dict.

Comment: Check edit in the "Possible Solution" tag. You must initialize a new dictionary inside the key `x` before being able to access it -- doing `dict['level1']['level2'] = 'var'` is not enough, you must first declare `level1` as a `dict` by at least doing `dict['level1'] = {}` and then doing `dict['level1']['level2'] = 'var'`.

Comment: I was able to get done what I was expecting. Your comment gave the hint. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear! :)

Answer (score 3):

In your last line, `dict[x]` = `dict['a']` = `0`. `0` is just an integer - there's no such thing as `0['c']`, so there's no such thing as `0[z]`, so there's no such thing as `dict[x][z]`.